# how to hide div onclick of radiobuttonlist button

Tags: asp.net

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdPaymentBy"  runat="server">
 <asp:ListItem   Text="<b>male</b>" Value="Paypal"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem   Text="<b>female</b>" Value="payuMoney"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="<b>both</b>" Value="payuMoney"></asp:ListItem>
   </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

My Question is:
when we click on radiobutton ,how to hide paticular div ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code to hide div on radiobutton click

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#RadioDiv input').click(function () {
    var value=$("#RadioDiv input:radio:checked").val();

       if(value=="Paypal")
        {

            $("#divID").hide();
        }

  });
</script>
```